# Trinity failed with differential expression analysis test

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I tried running the DE test that comes with Trinity after installing everything that's mentioned on their website, but ran into this error.

```
WARNING: This EdgeR comparison failed...

CMD: R --vanilla -q < Trinity_trans.counts.matrix.diauxic_shift_vs_plateau.EdgeR.Rscript
> library(edgeR)
>
> data = read.table("/usr/local/trinityrnaseq-r2013.02.25/sample_data/test_full_edgeR_pipeline/Trinity_trans.counts.matrix", header=T, row.names=1, com='')
> col_ordering = c(4,1)
> rnaseqMatrix = data[,col_ordering]
> rnaseqMatrix = round(rnaseqMatrix)
> rnaseqMatrix = rnaseqMatrix[rowSums(rnaseqMatrix)>=10,]
> conditions = factor(c(rep("plateau", 1), rep("diauxic_shift", 1)))
>
> exp_study = DGEList(counts=rnaseqMatrix, group=conditions)
Calculating library sizes from column totals.
> exp_study = calcNormFactors(exp_study)
> et = exactTest(exp_study, dispersion=0.1)
Comparison of groups:  plateau - diauxic_shift
> tTags = topTags(et,n=NULL)
> write.table(tTags[tTags$table$PValue <= 0.05,], file='Trinity_trans.counts.matrix.diauxic_shift_vs_plateau.edgeR.DE_results', sep='   ', quote=F, row.names=T)
> source("/usr/local/trinityrnaseq-r2013.02.25/Analysis/DifferentialExpression/R/rnaseq_plot_funcs.R")
> pdf("Trinity_trans.counts.matrix.diauxic_shift_vs_plateau.edgeR.DE_results.MA_n_Volcano.pdf")
> result_table = tTags$table
> plot_MA_and_Volcano(result_table$logCPM, result_table$logFC, result_table$FDR)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
Calls: plot_MA_and_Volcano -> plot_MA -> plot -> plot.default -> xy.coords
Execution halted
Error, cmd: R --vanilla -q < Trinity_trans.counts.matrix.diauxic_shift_vs_plateau.EdgeR.Rscript died with ret (256)  at /usr/local/trinityrnaseq-r2013.02.25/util/..//Analysis/DifferentialExpression/run_DE_analysis.pl line 416.
```